# Acuant SDK does't work with support v7 appcompat lib in android

Tags: android, sdk, camera, scanning

When I did simple example it is working fine but if I add support v7 appcompat lib, it is crashing on opening camera on marshmello,Nought.
But it works in android Lollipop few devices and crashed in Marshmallow and Nougat .
Any one used this library, can you help me to fix it.

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get Runtime permission to use the camera on after Marshmellow devices.

First check if the user grant the permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Then, you could use this to request to the user:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, requestCode);
```

And in marshmallow it appears the dialog

Know more about permission here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html